# What's the meaning of the 1 on the file folder icon on the sidebar?

Tags: gui

What does the number 1 indicate on the folder icon? seems to be a sticky value.

Ubuntu 23.10 (mantic)

[image: file folder icon sidebar GUI]

Comment: It shows you the number of unread notifications from that specific app, in this case File. If you started copying a large file or a large folder, the notification may tell you that copying is complete.

Comment: that's it @user68186 thank you. It did not intuitively gave me hint that I had to remove the message from the notifications. But now I know where to find it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.